# SQL Count empty fields

Tags: sql, select, null

I'm not sure if this is possible or if it is, how to do it -

I have the following data in a database -

```
id     |    improve |   timeframe |  criteria |  impact
-------+------------+-------------+-----------+--------- 
1      |            |    Test     |   Test    |    Test
2      |    Test    |             |   Test    |   
3      |            |    Test     |           |    
-------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------
```

Ignoring the id column, how can I determine the number of fields out of the remaining 12 that are not null using an SQL query?

I have started with -

```
SELECT improve, timeframe, impact, criteria 
FROM data 
WHERE improve IS NOT NULL 
  AND timeframe IS NOT NULL 
  AND impact IS NOT NULL 
  AND criteria IS NOT NULL;
```

This only returns the number of rows, ie. 3.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get the sum of all non empty fields. So, `count(improve) where improve is not null + count(timeframe) where timeframe is not null`, and so on, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, I need the sum of all non empty fields, sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: how to know empty rows in a single column? Thanks

Comment: Should change the title of this question, because it is asking "empty" fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT count(improve) + count(timeframe) + count(impact) + count(criteria) FROM data
```

Comment: At the moment this returns all fields, where am I going wrong in retrieving the sum of all non-empty fields?

Comment: @Tom, did you try this query? Also, you need to clarify what you mean with "non-empty". In your question you talked about "not null", which is a difference in most databases except Oracle. This query counts all fields which are not null.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin and have set the fields as Varchar default NULL but it is still showing the sum of all fields whether they are null or not. Does this sound right?

Comment: MySQL makes a difference between empty strings and null values. You probably have empty strings, not null values. If you don't want to count these either, you can use this query `SELECT count(nullif(improve,'')) + count(nullif(timeframe,'')) + count(nullif(impact,'')) + count(nullif(criteria,'')) FROM data`

Answer (score 6):

Something like this may get you going in the right direction

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN improve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
CASE WHEN timeframe IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE 1 END +
CASE WHEN criteria IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE 1 END +
CASE WHEN impact IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE 1 END)
from
data
```

Comment: This actually counts **non** null columns!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, COUNT(improve) + COUNT(timeframe) + COUNT(impact) + COUNT(criteria) FROM data GROUP BY id;

Answer (score -1):

**IF you're using SQL Server,** use DATALENGTH().

```
SELECT improve, timeframe, impact, criteria 
FROM data 
WHERE DATALENGTH(improve) > 0 
AND DATALENGTH(timeframe) > 0 
AND DATALENGTH(impact) > 0 
AND DATALENGTH(criteria) >0;
```

DATALENGTH returns the length of the string in bytes, including trailing spaces. It sounded as though you're OK with blank fields, so DATALENGTH does the job. Otherwise, you could also use LEN(), which would trim any trailing space.

**IF you are using MySQL,** you can use CHARACTER_LENGTH, which removes trailing white space and then gives you a character count of the field you want to check.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Sum(case when improve is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when timeframe is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when impact is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when criteria is null then 0 else 1 end)
FROM data
group by improve, timeframe, impact, criteria
```

Comment: You should really look up the `COUNT` function